# Error adding a numeric password field on my android project

Tags: java, android, layout

I added a Password (numeric) field to the layout for my project and this errors appeared

```
> Error: String types not allowed (at 'inputType' with value
> 'numberPassword').    main.xml    /[proyect name]/res/layout  line 8  Android
> AAPT Problem
```

Any idea why this happened?

Answer (score 3):

The problem lies with the SDK version that your app is being targeted for.

numberPassword was not an available input type until 3.0.

If you're using Eclipse, you can see this in action by viewing the Graphical Layout and changing the SDK to Android 3.0 or above.  After you do so, the error will go away.

Change the SDK back to 2.3.3 or below, and the error will reappear.